# How to Decompile HP LaserJet Pro M12w firmware in Ghidra

Tags: firmware, ghidra, arm, decompile

I'm trying to decompile HP LaserJet Pro M12w firmware with Ghidra,
after download the HP LaserJet Firmware Update Utility from [this link](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/printers/lj_M12/win/hp_LJPM11-M13_Full_Solution-v20180815-10229428_1.exe), when I look at this file, I found two file, hpm12a.pkg and hpm12w.pkg (w means wifi).
When I analysis hpm12w.pkg with binwalk, got following information:

- ELF, 32-bit MSB executable, version 1 (SYSV)
- Copyright string: "Copyright (c) 1996-2001 Express Logic Inc. * ThreadX ARM9/ARM Version G4.0.4.0 *"
- Copyright string: "Copyright (c) 2008   Marvell Semiconductor, Inc. All Rights Reserved."
  ...

This is my question: after add hpm12w.pkg to Ghidra, I could not find right "Language" for this binary file